# How to Change Many buttons text value with one button but different values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I've tried many ways to make this but it give me the same result every time 
I want to make a button (random) that change the text of other many buttons(Choose Vacation) with random different value for each one but not same value 
here is a mini example if any one could help

```
class ShiftChange extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Off: " Choose Vacation",
            rand: "random",
        }
    }
    Change = () => (
        this.setState({
            Off: "Off"
        })
    )
    shuffle = () => {
        if (this.state.Off !== "Off") {
            var x = ["2:00 to 11:00 ", "3:00 to 12:00", "12:00 to 9:00"]
            this.setState({
                Off: x[Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length)]
            })
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.Change}>
                    {this.state.Off}
                </button>
                <button onClick={this.Change}>
                    {this.state.Off}
                </button>
                <button onClick={this.shuffle}>
                    random
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

[Button snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oVh5.png)

Answer (score 0):

On change function try to set the state value to something else because you are try to set the value to 'off' so the if condition never gets true so the values never change

Have a nice day!!

Comment: it would be true if one of the buttons not changed 
so what if there is many buttons didn't change how can i shuffle them with random different values . this is the question here

Answer (score 0):

Here are some issue in your code .

1. You are setting state **Off** in **shuffle** function which is setting 
   only   one time  **Off** state value **not two times** (<--note here)

What you can do create two state variable and set according to it.

Here how you can do it :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Off1: " Choose Vacation",
      Off2: "Choose Vacation",
      rand: "random"
    };
  }
  Change = () =>
    this.setState({
      Off1: "Off1",
      Off2: "Off2"
    });
  shuffle = () => {
    if (this.state.Off !== "Off") {
      var x = ["2:00 to 11:00 ", "3:00 to 12:00", "12:00 to 9:00"];
      this.setState({
        Off1: x[Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length)],
        Off2: x[Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length)]
      });
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.Change}>{this.state.Off1}</button>
        <button onClick={this.Change}>{this.state.Off2}</button>
        <button onClick={this.shuffle}>random</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is working demo link : https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-butterfly-rybjk

Comment: this might be closer answer .. but what if there is too many buttons about 100+ in a table with the same functions ? should i make as many states as  number of buttons ? this would be annoying 
+ now the change function don't affect  the button itself only but both of them